# RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Users) could not be initialized.'

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have installed  Zend framework.Its working demo page.after install Module its not open showing error.

```
 RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Users) could not be initialized.'
D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php:195 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php(169): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php(96): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule('Users') #2 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #4 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Ev in
```

module.config.php

```
 <?php
return array(
'controllers' => array(
'invokables' => array(
'Users\Controller\Index' => 'Users\Controller\IndexController',
),
),
'router' => array(
'routes' => array(
'users' => array( 'type' => 'Literal',
'options' => array(
// Change this to something specific to your module
'route' => '/users',
'defaults' => array(
// Change this value to reflect the namespace in which
// the controllers for your module are found
'__NAMESPACE__' => 'Users\Controller',
'controller' => 'Index',
'action' => 'index',
),
),
'may_terminate' => true,
'child_routes' => array(
// This route is a sane default whendeveloping a module;
// as you solidify the routes for your module,however,
// you may want to remove it and replace it with more
// specific routes.
'default' => array(
'type' => 'Segment',
'options' => array(
'route' =>'/[:controller[/:action]]',
'constraints' => array(
'controller' =>'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
'action' =>'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
),
'defaults' => array(
),
),
),
),
),
),
),
'view_manager' => array(
'template_path_stack' => array(
'users' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
),
),
);
```

Module.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2015 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Module.php

```
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2015 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

I don't know where i did mistake.after install skeleton Zend application working good.after install Module its showing error.My module Name 'users'

Comment: Can you share your `User` module's Module.php contents instead of Application?

Comment: @ foozy updated code please  take and look my code

Answer (score 0):

You have **Application** namespace declaration in both **Application** and **User** module's Module.php classes. This seems problematic. (I'm not aware your directory scaffolding, did you correctly separate your modules into correct directories?)

Every module should have different namespaces, respectively. As first step, you should change the User module's namespace declaration from

```
namespace Application;
```

to

```
namespace User;
```

You may also want to read some documentation about [PHP Namespaces](http://www.phptherightway.com/#namespaces).